# Detecting if is zoom-in or zoom-out with leaflet

Tags: leaflet

How can I know when the user is zooming in or zooming out? I want to start an animation if the user zooms after some level. Is it possible to know this when the event zoomstart is triggered?

Comment: `map.on('zoomstart', function(e) { do something });`

Comment: But how do I know if is zoom-in or zoom-out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How can I know when the user is zooming in or zooming out?

At every `zoom` level, calculate how much `map.getZoom()` has changed.

> Is it possible to know this when the event zoomstart is triggered?

No.

Consider the following scenario: A user, using a touchscreen (phone/tablet).

The user puts two fingers down on the screen. Half a frame after, one of the fingers moves a couple of pixels towards the center, triggering a pinch-zoom with a tiny change in the zoom level.

Your code catches the `zoomstart` and `zoom` events that happen inmediately after. "I know!" - your code says - "The user is zooming out!".

And then the user starts moving their fingers wider and wider, zooming in. And your code gets confused.

But the user changes their mind, and then starts zooming out for whatever reason. And then in again. And then out again. And then they lift the fingers and the zoom snaps to a zoom level.

This is why you can **not** know what the final zoom level is going to be when you listen to a `zoomstart` or `zoom` event in Leaflet.

Comment: Ok, what about the idea to fire `zoomstart` everytime the user is changing the direction?

Comment: No. The semantics are clear: there's a `zoomstart` when an interaction *starts* changing the zoom level, and a `zoomend` when that interaction *ends*.

Comment: If you want to «start an animation if the user zooms after some level», rely on `zoom` events and trigger stuff when the map's zoom is *higher* (not "equal or higher") than your threshold.

Comment: is it possible to cancel zoom event on zoomstart?

Comment: I would be happy to get notified to get the current zoomed value if that is a float that would be fine. I would apply that "in progress" zoom level too.