# Leaflet zoom direction with javascript events

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I need functionality to check in what direction is map scrolled. 
I show some text on a map using tooltips and need to change font-size depending on zoom level.

I had tried with **`'wheel'`** event but it is fired only out of a Map.
Also as I know there is no direction event on **`'zoomstart'`** and **'zoomend'** events.

I know that checking zoom direction is not Leaflet's by the book way but any suggestion or solution will help me a lot.

Comment: Can't you use `getZoom()`?

Comment: getZoom() is return next zoom level on 'zoomend  'event and current zoom Level on 'zoomstart'. I need exactly event that catch wheel event on map.

Comment: The `zoom` event should "_Fired repeatedly during any change in zoom level, including zoom and fly animations._"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting if is zoom-in or zoom-out with leaflet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39893070/detecting-if-is-zoom-in-or-zoom-out-with-leaflet)